# How to include the row number when loading a file to array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I load a file into `ndarray` as

```
data = np.loadtxt("data.txt", delimiter=",", usecols=(2,3))
y= data[:,1]
x = row number of y
```

How can I set the row numbers to *x*, instead of the values of a column?

File

```
22,13,4,0.9507
22,13,12,0.9446
22,13,22,1.9507
22,13,31,1.0506
22,13,34,0.9806
22,13,35,0.9511
```

Desirable output

```
[[ 0  0.9507]
 [ 1  0.9446]
 [ 2  1.9507]
 [ 3  1.0506]
 [ 4  0.9806]
 [ 5  0.9511]]
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: @CoryMadden I updated the question with samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row number is just a sequence, you can generate the sequence with `np.arange` and then bind it with the actual array with `np.stack` or `np.column_stack`:

```
np.stack((np.arange(y.size), y), axis=1)
```

or:

```
np.column_stack((np.arange(y.size), y))
```

---

```
y = np.array([3,2,2,1,4,5])
np.stack((np.arange(y.size), y), axis=1)
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 5]])
```

Comment: @CoryMadden I edited the question, the answer was for the previous edit where starting row was 1. I edited as I thought it would be easier to start the row number by 0.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that one.

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> pd.read_csv('data.txt', usecols=(3,)).reset_index().values
array([[ 0.    ,  0.9446],
       [ 1.    ,  1.9507],
       [ 2.    ,  1.0506],
       [ 3.    ,  0.9806],
       [ 4.    ,  0.9511]])
```

An index ranging from zero to n -1 is automatically added if not specified.  Resetting the index adds it as the left most column in the dataframe, from where you can get the numpy array via `.values`.